# QObject::connect -- Event -- QFtp stateChange(int)

Tags: c++

So I'm a C# developer and I am learning C++ (as hobby).

I use Qt for that, and for practice i want create a FTP client, but I have a problem.

I create an event when the ftp connection state changed, so I want use the event `stateChanged(int)`

But i have a problem :

```
Error: no matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(QFtp*&, const char*, Ftp* const, const char*)'
```

My code :

```
    #include "ftp.h"

QString _host;
QString _User;
QString _Pass;

Ftp::Ftp(QObject *parent,QString host,QString user,QString pass)
{
    ftp =new QFtp(parent);
    QObject::connect(ftp,SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)),this,SLOT(FtpStateChang(int)));
    _host = host;
    _User = user;
    _Pass = pass;
}

void Ftp::Connect()
{
    ftp->connectToHost(_host,21);
    ftp->login(_User,_Pass);
}

void Ftp::FtpStateChang(int state)
{
    //EVENT
}

QString Ftp::CheckConnection()
{
    Connect();
    switch(ftp->state())
    {
        case QFtp::LoggedIn:
            return "LoggedIn";
        case QFtp::Unconnected:
            return "Unconnected";
        case QFtp::Connecting:
            return "Connecting";
        case QFtp::Closing:
            return "Closing";
    }
}
```

Please tell me why. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does your `Ftp` class inherit `QObject`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, inherit from `QObject` if you forgot and do not forget to place the `Q_OBJECT` macro in the `private` section of your Class-Definition ( since you declare your own slot )